# NX NextJs App doesn't work on read-only docker container

Tags: docker, next.js, nxjs

I have a Dockerfile that builds an nx app and then serves it, however that docker container runs in read-only mode and that causes this problem:

```
    EROFS: read-only file system, open '/app/node_modules/.cache/nx/project-graph.json~c3501751'
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/app/node_modules/.cache/nx/project-graph.json~c3501751'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at writeFileSync (node:fs:2249:35)
    at writeJsonFile (/app/node_modules/nx/src/utils/fileutils.js:56:28)
    at writeCache (/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/nx-deps-cache.js:105:43)
    at /app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/build-project-graph.js:58:44
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:164:62)
```

I don't have serve listed in my cache operations
`"cacheableOperations": ["build", "lint", "test", "e2e"],`
so I don't know why it's trying to cache on `nx serve` (@nx/next:server)

I tried adding `"skipNxCache": true` to the `taskRunnerOptions` in nx.json
and also I tried using the `--skip-nx-cache` flag in the serve command
and nothing works.

Why is serve using cache? any recommendations on how to disable it?

I'm using nx 16.3.0

Comment: It is not an option to create a volume / and mount at the nx cache location.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to disable cache write:

```
ENV NX_DAEMON=false
ENV NX_SKIP_NX_CACHE=true
ENV NX_CACHE_PROJECT_GRAPH=false
```

The explanation is, if the Daemon is enabled cache is written even if the nx skip cache flag is set to true. Disabling the Daemon then disabling the cache project graph actually disables the cache.
More details [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/16182#issuecomment-1625646889)